# How to replace / delete some of the special characters present in a string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Context -**

I have few strings which have some special characters in them which are supposed to be replaced / deleted to get the desired output.

**What we need to do? -**

Like I mentioned above -

1. Delete the character `@` if any are present in the string.
2. Replace the character `/` with `_`

**For Instance** -

Example 1) -

Input String -

```
string = "noMad@/places/-/contents/imr/-/pops/-"
```

Desired result-

```
output_string = "noMad_places_-_contents_imr_-pops_-"
```

Example 2) -

Input String -

```
string = "cat@/places/-/chart/rules"
```

Desired result-

```
output_string = "cat_places_-_chart_rules"
```

How can we do this in Ruby? Any leads would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Use `tr`

```
string = 'cat@/places/-/chart/rules'

p string.delete('@').tr('/','_')
```

output

```
"cat_places_-_chart_rules"
```

Comment: You can also `tr('@', '')` which has the effect of deleting. Clearly `delete` is more self-explanatory, but if you really like `tr`, and it deserves all the love it gets, you can do both!

Comment: ...or `string.gsub(/[@\/]/) { |s| s == '@' ? '' : '_' } #=> "cat_places_-_chart_rules"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **String class method named *gsub()***
The basic syntax of gsub in Ruby:

`str.gsub!(pattern, replacement)`

Parameters: Here, *str* is the given string. *pattern* may be specified regex or character set to be removed. *replacement* is the set of characters which is to be put.

For example

```
string1 = "noMad@/places/-/contents/imr/-/pops/-"
puts string1.gsub("@","").gsub("/","_")
```

Output

```
noMad_places_-_contents_imr_-_pops_-
```